# What is this coolness rank?

Tags: splatoon

When you are starting a game you see something that is called a coolness rank, I guess. Of course, I am way off the charts with my `On Fire!`, but I really want to know what it does, and more importantly, what can I do with it?

[image: My coolness level]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This rating tells you how many games you've won in series, though it's a bit more complicated than that.

Whenever you win a game you gain a few points, and when you lose a game you lose some of those points. The more points you have, the higher your rating gets, and the more points you risk of losing.

As far as I can tell, the only use of these points, is in talking to Judd (the cat). He should be able to tell you the above in slightly more detail, then he'll proceed to reward you with coins. The higher your rating is, the more he'll pay you as a reward.

The rating is reset every 4 hours, by the way, so you should talk to Judd to redeem your reward regularly.

If you don't know where Judd is: He's right in front of the lobby, sleeping.

[image]
<sup>Judd, sleeping in front of the Lobby. Image from [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/splatoon/Judd).</sup>

Comment: Correction: Your ranking is reset every 4 hours.

Comment: @KevinDuke. Thanks for the correction, I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 14):

Your coolness rank shows generally how well you've been doing in the online multiplayer during the current session. The session changes when the stages change, which is every four hours (despite that Judd's tip claims that it resets daily).

There are four different ranks. The highest number of flags you can have is nine, and the lowest is zero. Winning while your rank is low will gain you more flags than winning while your rank is high, and losing while your rank is low will cost you less flags than losing when your rank is high. Your coolness rank can go above 9.0 (I've gotten it as high as 44.0), but no more than 9 flags will be displayed.

The only thing you can receive from your coolness rank is coins, which will be given by Judd the cat in the plaza. You can receive coins once per coolness rank per session, for a total of 1,400 coins. When you talk to Judd, he will include any unclaimed rewards for lower ranks that you haven't yet collected in that session. Rewards are based on your highest rank so far during that session. You will not receive any unclaimed rewards when the session resets (also despite what Judd's tip implies).

Here are the ranks and corresponding rewards:

- Chill - 0 flags - no reward
- Toasty - 0.5 to 3 flags - 100 coins
- Smokin' - 3.5 to 6 flags - 300 coins
- So Hawt! - 6.5 to 9 flags - 1,000 coins

The text associated with each of these ranks depends on localization; these ones are for the American localization ("On Fire!", which you mentioned, is the European equivalent to "So Hawt!").

Comment: Not sure if those values are correct. In the NA version you get 1400 coins for So Hawt rank

Comment: @KevinDuke When you get 1,400, that's because your rank is "So Hawt!" and you did not collect the 100 or 300 coins for the two lower ranks yet, so Judd includes them with the 1,000 for the top rank.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the number of coins you get is entirely dependent on the number of flags. 4 flags leads to 400 coins, 18 flags leads to 1800 coins, etc.